# AnkhSVN not pulling in files created by another user in the same solution in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, ankhsvn

I have a VS sln with about 5 projects that I created along with the majority of the files in each project.  I commit changes to SVN via Ankh and it's just peachy. Another developer just started and he can retrieve the files via VS and can also commit to the repository (I aded him as a full control user), but I can't retrieve them via Ankh.  I can see the files he's added in the repo-browser, but when getting project updates or even getting the entire sln from the server, I don't get his files.

He can retrieve anything I add, but not the other way around.  Is there some user setting that I'm missing that would create this situation?  I just noticed it today, and I need his files for unit testing and a full build ASAP.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update of AnkhSVN might help. From your description, you ran into this well known bug:
http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#incompleteupdate

To get this working again, update your working copy with the depth set to `infinity` (since I don't use AnkhSVN, I can't tell you where that option is, but I'm sure there's a way to do that).

Answer (score 3):

This may be caused by a recently discovered [bug](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3569) in Subversion that's triggered when updating a *folder* using AnkhSvn. We're in the process of building a workaround for this in AnkhSvn, and a fix in Subversion.

The real fix in Subversion takes a lot of work, and will take some time to get implemented. The workaround in AnkhSvn should be available in AnkhSvn daily builds soon.

The most stable way to fix the problem is to check out a new working copy, and discard the old one. You can safely commit changes from the old working copy, or move that changed files over to the new working copy so you can commit them from there.

Until the workaroudn is in place, don't right-click -> Update folders. Updating at solution/project and file(s) level is safe.

Comment: I was able to just pull a full copy by checking out the directory in TortoiseSVN and not using Ankh at all.  Odd, but it'll work for now.  Cheers.

Comment: Did you check it out again? Or did updating the directory help (just to determine what kind of issue this is/was)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an svn conflict?  That could prevent a directory from updating.

Other possible explanation is the sln file won't merge his updates into yours, or possibly he's not using visual studio at all.  Either way make sure the files are actually missing not just ommitted from the sln file.

Comment: The files aren't missing in the repository as I can browse to them, and he added them via VS.  I'm just stuck on why he can retrieve my additions, but I can't pull his.  Thanks

Comment: This bug still exists now and is driving me batty today!